# Pandas check which substring is in column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to create function which will create a new column in a pandas dataframe, where it figures out which substring is in a column of strings and takes the substring and uses that for the new column.

The problem being that the text to find does not  appear at the same location in variable `x`

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["var_m500_0_somevartext","var_m500_0_vartextagain",
 "varwithsomeothertext_0_500", "varwithsomext_m150_0_text"], 'x1': [4, 5, 6,8]})

finds = ["m500_0","0_500","m150_0"]
```

which of `finds` is in a given `df["x"]` row

I've made a function that works, but is terribly slow for large datasets

```
def pd_create_substring_var(df,new_var_name = "new_var",substring_list=["1"],var_ori="x"):
    import re
    df[new_var_name] = "na"
    cols =  list(df.columns)
    for ix in range(len(df)):
        for find in substring_list:
            for m in re.finditer(find, df.iloc[ix][var_ori]):
                df.iat[ix, cols.index(new_var_name)] = df.iloc[ix][var_ori][m.start():m.end()]
    return df


df = pd_create_substring_var(df,"t",finds,var_ori="x")

df 
                            x  x1       t
0      var_m500_0_somevartext   4  m500_0
1     var_m500_0_vartextagain   5  m500_0
2  varwithsomeothertext_0_500   6   0_500
3   varwithsomext_m150_0_text   8  m150_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best way:

```
df['t'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in finds if i in x]))
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
                            x  x1       t
0      var_m500_0_somevartext   4  m500_0
1     var_m500_0_vartextagain   5  m500_0
2  varwithsomeothertext_0_500   6   0_500
3   varwithsomext_m150_0_text   8  m150_0
```

And now, just adding to @pythonjokeun's answer, you can do:

```
df["t"] = df["x"].str.extract("(%s)" % '|'.join(finds))
```

Or:

```
df["t"] = df["x"].str.extract("({})".format('|'.join(finds)))
```

Or:

```
df["t"] = df["x"].str.extract("(" + '|'.join(finds) + ")")
```

Comment: the first you show is the fastest, for my large dataset of 180000 rows and unlike @pythonjokeun's answer it can run on python 3.5

Answer (score 3):

Does this accomplish what you need ?

```
finds = ["m500_0", "0_500", "m150_0"]
df["t"] = df["x"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(finds)})")
```

Comment: Nice one, i tried this, but just a little bit off and gave up on this idea

Answer (score 2):

Use [pandas.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

`df['x'].str.findall("|".join(finds))`

```
0    [m500_0]
1    [m500_0]
2     [0_500]
3    [m150_0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how large your dataset is, but you can use map function like below:

```
def subset_df_test():
  df = pandas.DataFrame({'x': ["var_m500_0_somevartext", "var_m500_0_vartextagain",
                         "varwithsomeothertext_0_500", "varwithsomext_m150_0_text"], 'x1': [4, 5, 6, 8]})

  finds = ["m500_0", "0_500", "m150_0"]
  df['t'] = df['x'].map(lambda x: compare(x, finds))
  print df

def compare(x, finds):
  for f in finds:
    if f in x:
        return f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df["t"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in finds if i in x][0])
```